# How to get the dataitem from e.target in the onDrag method of a Kendo TreeList (in Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, kendo-treelist

I have an `onDrag` method bound to the drag-event of a treeList.
In this method, I need to get the dataitem in the tr the user drags over.
But `e.target` only gets the td element.

```
exportObject.onDrag = function (e) {

    console.log(e.target); //output is td element
    //console.log(e.target.parentElement); //undefined
    console.log(this); //same as e.target
    //if(e.target.?ROW.DATAITEM?.SomeProp != "something") e.setStatus("k-i-cancel");
};
```

Comment: share your code via jsfiddle or similar site.

Comment: there is nothing special. I added code to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels like cheating, but if people searches and lands here, I make an answer here as well:
To get a hold of dataItem in drag event I use a ugly piece of code:

```
$(e.target).parents('.k-treelist').data('kendoTreeList').dataItem(e.target)
```

But as long as it's working!